# How can I get both test and live access token by one oauth connection

Tags: oauth, stripe-payments, access-token

Stripe provides OAuth connection flow.

From this OAuth connection, user can get access token with client_id and secret.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

Stripe provides live and test mode.

How can I get both of live and test access token by one OAuth connection?

Answer (score 1):

The access_token approach was deprecated by Stripe in early 2015. Instead, they built a new approach that lets you make API requests on behalf of all your connected accounts using your API key.

The idea is that you use the platform's API key (Live or Test) and then pass the id of the connected account (acct_123) in the `Stripe-Account` [header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header). Doing this means you only have to care about your own API key and nothing else.

Comment: Additional information about not using the `access_token` approach can be found in the Stripe Developer docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#api-keys